# Merge [google-people] and [google-people-api]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

[google-people](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-people) (309 questions) and [google-people-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-people-api) (157 questions) both refer to the exact same Google People API, and should be merged, leaving only [google-people](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-people) remaining (since that tag is shorter and more popular).

[google-people](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-people) description:

> There are two Google people APIs: The new Google People API lets you list authenticated users' contacts and retrieve profile information for authenticated users and their contacts. The deprecated Google+ People API lets you list authenticated user's circled people and retrieve profile information for the authenticated user.

[google-people-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-people-api) description:

> The People API lets you list and manage the authenticated user's Contacts and retrieve profile information for authenticated users and their contacts.

Comment: I think it's better to have [tag:google-people-api] as the main tag because the official name is [People API](https://developers.google.com/people).

Comment: Google-people could be confused with Googlers.  I concur with keeping the API tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I went ahead and synonymed the two to [google-people-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-people-api) (keeps it consistent with other tags like [google-ads-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-ads-api)). We can merge soon if there's no objections.